# I couldn't change php.ini in Xampp

Tags: xampp

For some reason I should change some values in my php.ini but when I applied  changes nothing happened.I Google that problem but I realized Apache need to restart but after restart my Apache nothing happened.
I really need to solve in this problem .I installed VMware before I installed xampp in my computer i tell that because i guess xampp and vmware are not working 
well together.

Answer (score 0):

have you opened the php.ini in and administration mode? Sometimes a simple notepad is not saving the file properly. Try installing Notepad++ and open the php.ini and while you're saving a prompt should pop-up asking for admin privilege and reopen the file.

Comment: I used Sublime for edit my php.ini .is it necessary to use Notepad++??

Comment: Ah, should work in sublime as well. Could you insert what changes do you need to apply in php.ini? There must be something wrong in there

Comment: For example I need changing display_errors in my php.ini .

Comment: so what exactly that line of code looks like? Please copy paste couple of lines (and if there is # at the beginning which should have been deleted)